# Threaded Windows Service - SmtpClient Issues

Tags: c#, multithreading, castle-windsor, smtpclient

We're writing a threaded service using topshelf / windsor / masstransit to pick up messages off of MSMQ and then send an e-mail off with PDF attachment.

Every now and again the SmtpClient.Send() method throws this error message:

> An asynchronous call is already in progress. It must be completed or canceled before you can call this method.

I've got the SmtpClient set up as .LifeStyle.Transient in Windsor, so my understanding is that each thread should get its own instance?

Any idea how I can around this, short of locking that part of the code. Which would kind of defeat the purpose of the threads.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Transient` shouldn't just create a new instance per thread, but a new instance for every request.

I'd try to confirm that you're truly getting a new instance of SmtpClient - make sure you're not sticking it in a static field or otherwise somehow ending up with the same reference. You could try spitting the result from `GetHashCode()` into the Console each time you send an email to see if they're all using the same object.

Failing that, my only suggestion is to try and strip it down to a really simple example - if you don't find the issue in doing this, you can post the code here and someone might be able to help.

Comment: Yes transient always gives you a new instance, no exceptions. The stacktrace and context of whatever is causing the issue would be good. I doubt that's related directly to Windsor.

Comment: The GetHashCode idea helped alot. Ended up being the owning class (the consumer) that was only being instantiated once. Moved some code around and its working fine now! Thanks for the help!